# Validation for not more than one decimal (i.e 2.2 not 2.2.3)

Tags: javascript

I want to create a script function which will validate if the user input contains more than one decimal i.e 2.434 should be the correct number but if the user tries to input a NUMBER LIKE 2.4.5.6 it will not take the input in the field. It will take only number after a decimal point but not another single decimal point. no 2.2.2. but 2.2222. Will use it in a .net page.

tried different patterns like ^-{0,1}\d+.{0,1}\d*$ but could not get result. added the function i am already using. need to add the decimal part in the given code.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var first;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode == 46) {
            return true;
         }
        if (charCode == 46  || charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || 
          charCode > 57))
            return false;


        return true;
    }
```

text box will take input when 2.22 or 3.455654 but won't take 2.3.34.4. when the user writes something like this the cursor won't change the position or take the input number.

Comment: this code does not help. Please create a stack snippet or demo using jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: This code only validates the key pressed, not the entire string.

Comment: use `\.` (in Regex) because it's special operator for any character.

Comment: use `^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 1):

The code provided does not validate the entire string. It just checks that the key pressed is a digit, which does not help much. There are many ways to do what you want:

**1- Browser validation using `type="number"`:**

You can use an input with type "number"; then the browser will do a validation on its own before the form submits (this also accepts integers though):

```
<input type="number" name="decimal" />
```

**2- Browser validation using the `pattern`attribute:**

A handy property you can set for `input`s is the `pattern` attribute. You can set it to the desired regex, and the browser will make sure the user's input matches the regex before submitting the form.

```
<input type="text" name="decimal" pattern="^-?\d+\.?\d*$" />
```

**3- Custom validation with Javascript:**

This approach definitely gives you more flexibility, and allows you to validate once the user typed the input, instead of validating on form submit.

Assuming you have a text input, you can listen to the `onchange` event to validate the entire string, after the user has finished typing their input.

**Edit:** As for the regular expression, you need to escape the dot, so replace (`.` by `\.`). Plus, `{0, 1}` is equivalent to `?`, as pointed out by @CodeManiac in the comments.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("decimal-input");
input.onchange = function() {
  var text = this.value;
  if(!text.match(/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/)) {
    this.value = ""; //clear input
    console.log("Please enter a valid decimal.");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="decimal-input" placeholder="Enter a decimal..."/> 
</form>
```

Comment: ***on side note:*** `-{0,1}` is same as `-?` also `.` is a meta character in regex, you need to escape it

Comment: @CodeManiac Oh yes, I did escape the dot in part 3- but forgot to do so in part 2-. Thanks for pointing this out! Answer updated.

Comment: In my whole application i have used textbox tag .. so input tag is out of option actually

Answer (score 0):

in the event target is the reference to the input element. So you are able to obtain the whole string

```
 function isNumberKey(evt) {
  s=evt.target.value;
   console.log(s);

 if (s.length !==0){
    arr=s.split(".");
    if (arr.length>0){
      return false;
  }
   ///... other checks...
 }
```

there might be also a dirty way to check the whole number

```
 try {
   x=eval(s*1) ;
   } catch (ex){
  return false
 }
```

or just do it on the enter key to implement a tiny calculator in your input ;)

Answer (score 0):

Funtion `setupField` is called with the id of an input field to be initialized with an onkeyup event that will only allow valid input to be entered into the field. The regular expression it uses allows an optional + or - sign. The number itself can be of the format: 123, 123., 123.45, or .45

To allow an initial entry of the `+`, `-`, or `.` characters, the regular expression must also consider these characters to be legal input. When the form is submitted, there is always the possibility that only one of these 3 characters or no characters at all have been entered. It is easy enough to test for a valid decimal number by testing `isNan(parseFloat(input))` against the input.

```
^(([+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?)|[+-]?(\.\d+)|[\+-\.])$
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

function setupField(field)
{
    let re = /^(([+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?)|[+-]?(\.\d+)|[\+-\.])$/;
    field.autocomplete = "off";
    field.saveValue = field.value;
    field.onkeyup = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (v === '' || re.test(v)) {
            field.saveValue = v;
        }
        else {
            field.value = field.saveValue;
        }
    };
    field.onchange = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(v)))
            console.log('You entered invalid input.');
    };
}

function init()
{
    setupField(document.getElementById('x'));
}
</script>
<body onload="init();">
    <input type="input" id="x" size="10">
</body>
</html>
```